# Как сделать отдельно окно play/pause, а в другом окне соответственно воспроизведение/пауза видео (QtMultimedia)

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtmultimedia

Как сделать отдельно окно `play`/`pause`, а в другом окне соотвественно `воспроизведение`/`пауза` видео (`QtMultimedia`) ?

Использовал стандартные `QtWidgets`, `QtMultimedia`, `QtMultimediaWidgets`

Получилось только в рамках одного окна, 
хотелось бы в виде двух раздельных окнах.

**main.py**:

```
    import sys
    
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton
    
    class VideoWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(VideoWindow, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Video Player Widget")
    
            self.mediaPlayer = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(None, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
    
            videoWidget = QtMultimediaWidgets.QVideoWidget()
    
            container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)
            lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            lay.addWidget(videoWidget)
    
            self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Show new Window", container)
            self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_window_2)
    
            self.playButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()                          # Кнопка Play
            self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.playButton.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
            self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)
    
            self.positionSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)      # Слайдер перемотки видео
            self.positionSlider.setRange(0, 0)
            self.positionSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setPosition)
    
            self.errorLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
            self.errorLabel.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                                          QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
    
            # Create new action                             # Создание самих кнопок
            openAction = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('open.png'), '&Open', self)
            openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
            openAction.setStatusTip('Open movie')
            openAction.triggered.connect(self.openFile)
    
            # Create exit action
            exitAction = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
            exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
            exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
            exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
    
            # Create menu bar and add action                  Создание Меню бара
            menuBar = self.menuBar()
            fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
            # fileMenu.addAction(newAction)
            fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
            fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
    
            # Create a widget for window contents
            wid = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
            self.setCentralWidget(wid)
    
            # Create layouts to place inside widget
            controlLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
            controlLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            controlLayout.addWidget(self.playButton)
            controlLayout.addWidget(self.positionSlider)
    
            layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            layout.addWidget(container)
            layout.addLayout(controlLayout)
            layout.addWidget(self.errorLabel)
    
            # Set widget to contain window contents
            wid.setLayout(layout)
    
            self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
            self.mediaPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.mediaStateChanged)
            self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
            self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.durationChanged)
            self.mediaPlayer.error.connect(self.handleError)
    
        def openFile(self):                                         # Выбор видео файла из QFileDialog
            fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "C:\\Users\\123.wmv",
                                                      QtCore.QDir.homePath())
            print(fileName)
            if fileName:
                self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
                    QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)))
                self.playButton.setEnabled(True)
    
    
    
        def play(self):                                             # Воспроизведение видео файла
            if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
                self.mediaPlayer.pause()
                print("pause real")
            else:
                self.mediaPlayer.play()
    
        def mediaStateChanged(self, state):
            if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
                print("меняем иконку")
                self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
            else:
                self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaPlay)) 
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        player = VideoWindow()
        player.resize(640, 480)
        player.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста пример, который у вас есть.

Comment: вроде закинул код правильно

Comment: объясните пожалуйста, для чего (зачем) вы решили  разделить визуализацию одного процесса в двух окнах?

Comment: Видео будет воспроизводится на другом большом мониторе(экране), а с маленкого монитора будет управлятся play/pause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо **Martin Fitzpatrick** за ваши руководства и удобное приложение.

Failamp - Простая сборка медиаплеера в PyQt5
https://github.com/learnpyqt/15-minute-apps/tree/master/mediaplayer

**mediaplayer.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *

from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

def hhmmss(ms):
    # s = 1000
    # m = 60000
    # h = 360000
    h, r = divmod(ms, 36000)
    m, r = divmod(r, 60000)
    s, _ = divmod(r, 1000)
    return ("%d:%02d:%02d" % (h,m,s)) if h else ("%d:%02d" % (m,s))

class ViewerWindow(QMainWindow):
    state = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        # Emit the window state, to update the viewer toggle button.
        self.state.emit(False)


class PlaylistModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, playlist, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlaylistModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.playlist = playlist

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            media = self.playlist.media(index.row())
            return media.canonicalUrl().fileName()

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self.playlist.mediaCount()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.player = QMediaPlayer()

        self.player.error.connect(self.erroralert)
        self.player.play()

        # Setup the playlist.
        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
        self.player.setPlaylist(self.playlist)

        # Add viewer for video playback, separate floating window.
        self.viewer = ViewerWindow(self)
        self.viewer.setWindowFlags(self.viewer.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.viewer.setMinimumSize(QSize(480,360))

        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()
        self.viewer.setCentralWidget(videoWidget)
        self.player.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)

        # Connect control buttons/slides for media player.
        self.playButton.pressed.connect(self.player.play)
        self.pauseButton.pressed.connect(self.player.pause)
        self.stopButton.pressed.connect(self.player.stop)
        self.volumeSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.player.setVolume)

        self.viewButton.toggled.connect(self.toggle_viewer)
        self.viewer.state.connect(self.viewButton.setChecked)

        self.previousButton.pressed.connect(self.playlist.previous)
        self.nextButton.pressed.connect(self.playlist.next)

        self.model = PlaylistModel(self.playlist)
        self.playlistView.setModel(self.model)
        self.playlist.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.playlist_position_changed)
        selection_model = self.playlistView.selectionModel()
        selection_model.selectionChanged.connect(self.playlist_selection_changed)

        self.player.durationChanged.connect(self.update_duration)
        self.player.positionChanged.connect(self.update_position)
        self.timeSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.player.setPosition)

        self.open_file_action.triggered.connect(self.open_file)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.show()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasUrls():
            e.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        for url in e.mimeData().urls():
            self.playlist.addMedia(
                QMediaContent(url)
            )

        self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

        # If not playing, seeking to first of newly added + play.
        if self.player.state() != QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            i = self.playlist.mediaCount() - len(e.mimeData().urls())
            self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(i)
            self.player.play()

    def open_file(self):
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "", "mp3 Audio (*.mp3);mp4 Video (*.mp4);Movie files (*.mov);All files (*.*)")

        if path:
            self.playlist.addMedia(
                QMediaContent(
                    QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)
                )
            )

        self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

    def update_duration(self, mc):
        self.timeSlider.setMaximum(self.player.duration())
        duration = self.player.duration()

        if duration >= 0:
            self.totalTimeLabel.setText(hhmmss(duration))

    def update_position(self, *args):
        position = self.player.position()
        if position >= 0:
            self.currentTimeLabel.setText(hhmmss(position))

        # Disable the events to prevent updating triggering a setPosition event (can cause stuttering).
        self.timeSlider.blockSignals(True)
        self.timeSlider.setValue(position)
        self.timeSlider.blockSignals(False)

    def playlist_selection_changed(self, ix):
        # We receive a QItemSelection from selectionChanged.
        i = ix.indexes()[0].row()
        self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(i)

    def playlist_position_changed(self, i):
        if i > -1:
            ix = self.model.index(i)
            self.playlistView.setCurrentIndex(ix)

    def toggle_viewer(self, state):
        if state:
            self.viewer.show()
        else:
            self.viewer.hide()

    def erroralert(self, *args):
        print(args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setApplicationName("Failamp")
    app.setStyle("Fusion")

    palette = QPalette()
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.WindowText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Base, QColor(25, 25, 25))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.AlternateBase, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ToolTipBase, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ToolTipText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ButtonText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.BrightText, Qt.red)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Link, QColor(42, 130, 218))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, QColor(42, 130, 218))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.HighlightedText, Qt.black)
    app.setPalette(palette)
    app.setStyleSheet("QToolTip { color: #ffffff; background-color: #2a82da; border: 1px solid white; }")

    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

---

**MainWindow.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(484, 371)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.playlistView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralWidget)
        self.playlistView.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.playlistView.setProperty("showDropIndicator", True)
        self.playlistView.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DropOnly)
        self.playlistView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.playlistView.setUniformItemSizes(True)
        self.playlistView.setObjectName("playlistView")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.playlistView)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.currentTimeLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.currentTimeLabel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 0))
        self.currentTimeLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.currentTimeLabel.setObjectName("currentTimeLabel")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.currentTimeLabel)
        self.timeSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralWidget)
        self.timeSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.timeSlider.setObjectName("timeSlider")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.timeSlider)
        self.totalTimeLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.totalTimeLabel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 0))
        self.totalTimeLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.totalTimeLabel.setObjectName("totalTimeLabel")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.totalTimeLabel)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.previousButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.previousButton.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/control-skip-180.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.previousButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.previousButton.setObjectName("previousButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.previousButton)
        self.playButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.playButton.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/control.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.playButton.setIcon(icon1)
        self.playButton.setObjectName("playButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.playButton)
        self.pauseButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pauseButton.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/control-pause.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pauseButton.setIcon(icon2)
        self.pauseButton.setObjectName("pauseButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.pauseButton)
        self.stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.stopButton.setText("")
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/control-stop-square.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.stopButton.setIcon(icon3)
        self.stopButton.setObjectName("stopButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stopButton)
        self.nextButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.nextButton.setText("")
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/control-skip.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.nextButton.setIcon(icon4)
        self.nextButton.setObjectName("nextButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.nextButton)
        self.viewButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.viewButton.setText("")
        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/application-image.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.viewButton.setIcon(icon5)
        self.viewButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.viewButton.setObjectName("viewButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.viewButton)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/speaker-volume.png"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label)
        self.volumeSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralWidget)
        self.volumeSlider.setMaximum(100)
        self.volumeSlider.setProperty("value", 100)
        self.volumeSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.volumeSlider.setObjectName("volumeSlider")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.volumeSlider)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 484, 22))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        self.menuFIle = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuFIle.setObjectName("menuFIle")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)
        self.open_file_action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.open_file_action.setObjectName("open_file_action")
        self.menuFIle.addAction(self.open_file_action)
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuFIle.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Failamp"))
        self.currentTimeLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0:00"))
        self.totalTimeLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0:00"))
        self.menuFIle.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "FIle"))
        self.open_file_action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open file..."))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да все работает Спасибо Вам !!!